# What would be best if i want to relate one table to few others? (Django models example)

Tags: django, database, nosql

Existed models:

```
class OrderDocument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_document_name)
    order_group = models.ForeignKey(OrderGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='documents')


class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_group = models.ForeignKey(OrderGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='orders')

class OrderGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I want to rewrite it for add ability to add OrderDocuments and choose with what table (Order or OrderGroup) it will related. Which way will the best in this case to implement it?

**It can be more than 2 relations in future.**

**I don't want using m2m in Order and OrderGroup**

**Order can be without OrderGroup**

Comment: Does Order has morethan one Order Document or Single Order document.?

Comment: @B.Anup more than one document

Comment: As per my understanding, Order group contains multiple Order but every order will be pointing to single Order group, so it is Many-to-One realtionship between Order and OrderGroup.  Every Order can contain multiple order documents, but every document will be pointing any one order. So it is again Many-to-one relationship between Order and Order document.
Please let me know, if my understanding is correct

Comment: @B.Anup i've updated question. Order have relation to OrderGroup but it can be null.

Comment: In that case, we can have the Foreign key(which can be null) in Order Table pointing to the row of OrderGroupWe can have Foreign Key(which can be null) in Order Document pointing to row of Order. Since every order will have order document, you can establish relation between OrderDocument and Order model instead of OrderGroup.  If there is a relation between OrderGroup row and Order model row, you can get documents for that Order